# How to call posts under a specific category on static front page?

Tags: posts, categories, customization, frontpage

[image]

I want to show posts according to categories on the static front page (home page) only.

Any suggestions.

1. can I show the contents from function.php or
2. which file is responsible for the static front page. I am using a custom theme.

Comment: Have you tried some plugin like [Content Blocks (Custom Post Widget)](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-widget/) And how can you show the content bock on a specific page?
It is recommended to install the [Widget Logic](https://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-logic/) plugin, this will give you complete flexibility on widget placement.

Comment: No I didn't tried any such plugin,thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress by default will look for `front-page.php` as the custom home page. For future reference, you will want to bookmark the [WordPress Theme Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) page. It includes a flow chart of what files WordPress will look for in order.

In the code of your `front-page.php` file, or an include you can conditionally call in `page.php`, you will want to insert a loop with a custom query using the [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) class. Say the category you want has the slug `news`:

```
$args = array (
   'category_name' => 'news'
);

$front_page_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

What this code will do is query the WordPress database and grab all posts that are categorized under `news`. You can do this by using the category's ID, but slug is probably the best way IMO because it doesn't involve having to look up the IDs in the table all the time and is more meaningful if someone else works with this code as well.

From there you just use the loop as you would any other page with one addition. Since you used a custom query, you have changed the `$post` global variable from the default so you will need to reset it. This is accomplished by using the `wp_reset_postdata()` function just before the `else` in your `if/then` statement. So your loop would look like this...

```
<?php if ( $front_page_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
   <?php while ( $front_page_query->have_posts() ) : $front_page_query->the_post(); ?>
      // Code for displaying the post
   <?php endwhile; ?>

   <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else: ?>

   // No Posts Found Code

<?php endif; ?>
```

You can add other arguments to refine your query such as limiting the number of posts it returns, skipping any password-protected posts, etc. Just add them to the `$args` array.

Comment: Thank You for sharing your knowledge. Though I solved this with other method. (Theme have some inbuilt widgets that helped me with some changes in their code)

Comment: +1 upvote from my side…...But I will surely try your method on fresh WordPress theme as it gives me more knowledge on WordPress file structure .Then I will accept this answer.